# Listing all visible implicits

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros

If it is at all possible, how to list all visible implicits using both reflection and macros? I need this to be able to analyze available typeclass instances.

### A use-case

```
case class Artist (name: String, genres: Set[Genre])
case class Genre (name: String)

object CatalogueDB extends MySQL {
  implicit val artistEntity = new Entity[Artist] {...}
  implicit val genreEntity = new Entity[Genre] {...}
}

trait MySQL {
  // Typeclasses let me restrict methods on `MySQL` to work only for types, 
  // which are associated with its instance.
  // E.g., the following method will only compile when either an `Artist` or
  // a `Genre` is passed to it when called on `CatalogueDB`:
  def save[e : Entity](e : e) ...
  // But also I need to be able to get a list of those types and 
  // instances of `Entity` typeclass to get the information
  // needed to generate the database schema and 
  // to perform other tasks like that.
  // So, the following method should somehow be able to have
  // the `Entity` instances for `Artist` and `Genre` at its disposal,
  // when called on `CatalogueDB`.
  def generateSchema ...
}
```

Comment: Hm...visible implicits are compile-time information. Not likely to be possible with reflection...that would be a _lot_ to store in the compiled form. Don't know about macros. They are at least compile-time processing.

Comment: So you need to get all possible implicits or just implicit instances of a given typeclass? Do you know anything about the the type arguments of these implicit instances? Also, could you elaborate on the use case?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako I need to get all instances of a given typeclass, not knowing the type arguments. For a use-case see the update to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way of doing exactly that at the moment. However, listing all members of a given class and checking whether they are implicit or not should be relatively easy - both at compile-time and at runtime.

Comment: By "members of a given class" do you imply instances?

Comment: I mean that it's possible, given a reference to `CatalogueDB`, to enumerate all its fields and methods, discovering `artistEntity` and `genreEntity`.